# how to delete a particular node in xml?

Tags: java, xml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

*i have one problem to delete the node in xml ,i have node list i stored some details,now i searched  by one node value (somevalue),and i want to delete the corresponding child nodes
here is xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Serverinformation>
<server>
<serverip>172.1.2.111</serverip>
<port>4000</port>
<dbip>162.2.1.111</dbip>
<dbname>sample</dbname>
<nor>1000</nor>
</server>
<server>
<serverip>182.1.2.111</serverip>
<port>6000</port>
<dbip>152.2.1.111</dbip>
<dbname>sample2</dbname>
<nor>1000</nor>
</server>
</Serverinformation>
```

//

```
 Element e = doc.getDocumentElement();
 NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("server");
 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
   Node node = nodeList.item(i);
   if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
         Element element = (Element) node;
         NodeList nodelist = element.getElementsByTagName("serverip");
                Element element1 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
                NodeList fstNm = element1.getChildNodes();
                String str=(fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue());
                String t="172.1.2.111";
                    if(str.equals(t))
                        { 
             element1.getParentNode().removeChild(element1);//here is the problem

          count=1;
          break
                        }               
              continue;
                }
          } 
        if(count==1)
        System.out.println("item found");
        else
        System.out.println("item not found");
    }
}
```

*so now i want to delete that node which has that value "172.1.2.111";what is wrong with this code*

Comment: What *is* wrong ? Do you get an exception ? Do you find the text node correctly ?

Comment: i got that node ,i can able to view all corresponding values,now my problem is remove method,

Comment: I dont see any issue - doc does get updated with the "<serverip>172.1.2.111</serverip>" Element removed.

Comment: did u c the xml file ,the value doesn't get updated.

Comment: Try this  nodelist.getParentNode().removeChild(element1); Probably you want to delete the server node not serverip element right. Please correct me if I am wrong.